# Fmx update control without applicatio.processmessages

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

What is the best way to update FMX control without using Apllication.Processmessages method, וn main  form.

Apllication.Processmessages call can cause to unwanted asynchrony user events to come in before operation completed.

We have old delphi  XE5 in ms windows 10, i tried repaint and invalidate but it not help.

Comment: It is a sound principle to avoid `Application.ProcessMessages`. Can you provide an example situation where you need to update an FMX control before the built in updating kicks in. Please provide a [mre] .

Comment: Don't do time-consuming work in the GUI thread. Use background threads for such work, and only use the GUI thread for GUI interaction. Then all controls will repaint themselves without any delay. (And you can move and resize your forms all the time, etc.)

Comment: For example , when user press button that process something that take a while, i want to disable the button (prevent another user click) and  insert  please wait message to the user. If i call Application.ProcessMessages During button  process  it is possible that the user press quick on other buttons that active. This can create unwanted asynchrony operation.

Comment: @user19437371 we understand what you want. You are like the bajillionst person to ask for this in Delphi's long history. What you have been told, by me and by Andreas, is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Have the `OnClick` handler disable the button, start a background thread/task to do the actual work, show the "please wait" message, and then **exit the `OnClick` handler**.  Do not block the main thread at all.  Let it run so it can process UI work normally as needed.

When your background work is finished, have the thread/task notify the main thread, which can then dismiss the "please wait" message and re-enable the button.

DO NOT do the actual work in the `OnClick` handler itself, and DO NOT call `Application.ProcessMessages()` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,In my code i need to block any operations on my GUI until the button process will finish. The button operation is mandatory before the user can continue.

Comment: @user19437371 that doesn't change what I said. You can simply disable the Form as a whole until the background work is finished. Or, if the "please wait" message is a pop-up Form, you can display it modally until the work is finished.